# Manage pending changes in a given Workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Is there a way to see pending changes for only the opened solution and not the entire Workspace without including/excluding respectives pending changes.?

I'm under TFS 2017 and VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

No. A workspace is a workspace is a workspace. If you want to isolate changes between solutions, then map individual workspaces for each solution.